# batch script (Bat) and passing a url

Tags: batch-file, url-rewriting, cmd, dos

I'm trying to do a script that opens several browsers at once.

I did:

```
SET /P ENTERURL="ENTER URL PLEASE: "

start /MIN "" "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" "%ENTERURL%"
start /MIN "" "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE" "%ENTERURL%"
```

It works OK for simple URLs but it breaks on URLs like

> www.bla.com/s/?a=d&gff&c=434#abc

Does anyone have something that works similar to urlencode in php?

Comment: I suppose, it's not a problem concerned with urlencode.  
Perhaps the `&` or `?` characters are problematic, but even with your test batch and url, I can't see any problems. Both browsers starts with the correct url.

Comment: Confirmed. Your particular example of a 'problem' URL didn't break it for me (Win XP SP2). Maybe you've got some other operations on `ENTERURL` after requesting it and before calling the browsers?

Comment: *What* exactly does break? Any error messages or behavior you might want to tell us?

Answer (score 2):

DOS doesn't allow you to use the & symbol in variables. You must use the ^ before it

Your code is correct, just use a different input.

```
www.bla.com/s/?a=d&gff&c=434#abc
```

becomes

```
www.bla.com/s/?a=d^&gff^&c=434#abc
```

Comment: Right, escape the & character with ^  :D